# One side margin in levelplot

Tags: r, raster

I want to have the levelplot margin only in the y axis. By default, margins show up in both x and y axis. Here is an example:

```
library (raster)
library(rasterVis)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
levelplot(r, margin=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may need to go with a different plotting solution, creating two separate plots and arranged by hand, or create a modified version of the `rasterVis::levelplot()` function.

As a hacky alternative you can try this, though it does have a few artifacts like leaving space for the `x` marginal panel in place, and also throws a Warning because of the empty data range, but it accomplishes what you want it to:

```
levelplot(r, margin=T, scales.margin=list(x=c(0,0), y=NULL))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will add this feature in the `rasterVis` package as soon as possible. Meanwhile, you can use the solution proposed by Forrest or this alternative:

```
p <- levelplot(r)
p$legend$top <- NULL
p
```

[image: levelplot with only one margin]

Comment: would you give an update on how I can do that in the new version when you added the feature?

Comment: @DNM It is already implemented ([commit](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis/commit/c976cc333a4f9576a146e1dc2cb590136ee6b969)) in the version available at [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rasterVis/)